# AppStore new app review with in-app purchase

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, review

I have a brand new app which contains an in-app purchase. I am trying to understand a correct order of the review. What has to be reviewed first: a brand new app or an in-app purchase

Firstly I tried to submit both binary and in-app purchase at the same time but got rejected. Apple's testers got 'undefined' price on my payment screen. However on all my devices and simulators price is loaded correctly and is shown in local currency. So I decided that maybe price is not working for Apple's testers because in-app purchase was not approved yet.

Yesterday I submitted my in-app purchase only for review without submitting a new binary. Right now in-app purchase is "waiting for review" and binary is still "rejected" with old unresolved issue.

Need an advice if I am doing this the correct way.

Comment: You need to submit the first in-app purchase for review at the same time as you submit the app for review.  Did you test a TestFlight build?  Do you retrieve the price from the `SKProduct` that you get from StoreKit?

Comment: yes, a build from testflight shows correct price. I am using react-native, for in-app purchases I have react-native-in-app-utils by chirag04

Comment: Is your in-app purchase available in all regions? Have you tested showing in different currencies?  you could try re-submitting in case it was some sort of temporary error, but you should probably change your code so that if you don't get an `SKProduct` then it just doesn't show the item for purchase rather than showing it with an "undefined" price.

Comment: in-app purchase is available in all regions. I tested in USD and EUR. Already 48 hours left but my in-app is still "waiting for review". I still didn't upload a new binary. Will wait a bit more

Comment: Nothing will happen until you resubmit your binary.

Comment: so I waited 5 full days (120 hours) and yet, nothing changed. In-app "waiting for review" status means nothing. It is not waiting for anything. Now I submitted a new binary

Comment: Yes, as I said, the first IAP waits for the binary review.  Since your binary was rejected you need to resolve that by submitting a new build.